# How can I run .jar file using .sh file?

Tags: java, shell, jar

I want to run .jar file in bash using shell script.
But I don't know how to write .sh file.
Can I get the example? I'm new to Shell Script (for example printing "hello java" jar file)

I don't mean it

```
java -jar [filename.jar]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you are using Linux/Mac machine.

create a file called `run.sh` with the following(make sure to replace [filename.jar] with your actual jar location, either relative or full path)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
java -jar [filename.jar]
```

execute the following in the terminal

`chmod +x run.sh`

now run it as like below

`./run.sh`

Comment: Sorry to my poor question.I use Linux. some people told me that is relative Classpath. what does it mean?

Comment: see [this](http://vedslinux.blogspot.com/2013/10/absolute-path-vs-relative-path-in-linux.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering me